# Why do libusb_devices **devs have a double pointer?

Tags: c, usb, libusb

I am always looking at a lot of open source code for libusb to get the information about the USB devices. In that they declared like,
**libusb_device **devs = NULL; //pointer to pointer to retrieve the device list.** But in some other implementations they were declared with a single pointer.

From my understanding the double pointer is used to dynamically change the value of the variable. So that if any device is newly connected means it will updated automatically in this devs field. This field is used in **libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);**. So that it will return proper device lists.

Is this right?

And one more thing: Is pointer to pointer we can say like a pointer to a one-dimensional array. Are all the connected devices stored like a one-dimensional array in libusb?

What will be the behaviour change if we declare with a single pointer?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but not right: This is not about being able to change things at run time.

Also, the [API](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#gac0fe4b65914c5ed036e6cbec61cb0b97) has triple `*`, not only two:

```
ssize_t libusb_get_device_list  (   libusb_context *    ctx,
        libusb_device ***   list 
    )
```

The device list is a list of device pointers (device pointer, hence the "inner" `*`); the C-style method of making a list of something is transporting a pointer to the first element, which in this case, is a pointer to a pointer to a device.

So, to write that list to the address you want to have it, the function needs a pointer to that list, so:

A pointer to a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: U mean the device list is having pointer to all devices to hide that pointers we are using double pointers?

Comment: @freeworld nothing to do with hiding; it's really just how you have a list of pointers.

Comment: :Thankyou.Suppose if we used as a single pointer also there will be any behaviour changes?or we need to take care anything for a single pointer?

Comment: @freeworld: of course, `**` is different than `*`. What did you expect? Seriously, this pointer handling should not confuse you at all. You will need to brush up your C knowledge first.